# OpenCV train cascade giving error "“Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled.”

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, training-data

so I've searched this online and this is a pretty common error but I've tried the given solutions to no avail. My cmd log is:

```
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata>opencv_traincascade -data my_trained -vec positives.vec -bg negativedata.txt -numPos 30 -numNeg 76 -numStages 15 -minHitRate 0.995 -w 197 -h 197 -featureType LBP -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcIdxBufSize 1024
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: my_trained
vecFileName: positives.vec
bgFileName: negativedata.txt
numPos: 30
numNeg: 76
numStages: 15
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
acceptanceRatioBreakValue : -1
stageType: BOOST
featureType: LBP
sampleWidth: 197
sampleHeight: 197
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.995
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
Number of unique features given windowSize [197,197] : 41409225

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====

<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   30 : 30
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
Cascade classifier can't be trained. Check the used training parameters.

C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata>
```

and my negativedata.txt file has 76 lines of info in the form:

```
negatives/1411814567410.jpg 1 2 2 199 199
negatives/20131225_192702.jpg 1 2 2 199 199
negatives/20131225_193214.jpg 1 2 2 199 199
negatives/20131225_193325.jpg 1 2 2 199 199
negatives/20131225_193327.jpg 1 2 2 199 199
negatives/20131225_193328.jpg 1 2 2 199 199
```

Please can someone help me pinpoint the issue because I'm still not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm doing this on a windows system. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue, apparently the bg file shouldn't contain constraints so now my file is in the form

```
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/ff.JPG
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/fifa.JPG
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/fred.JPG
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/IMG-20140718-WA0008-1.jpg
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/IMG-20150102-WA0013.jpg
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/IMG-20150120-WA0005.jpg
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/IMG_20140109_012313.jpg
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/IMG_20140405_205621.jpg
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/IMG_20140405_214225.jpg
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/IMG_20140405_214225_transparent.png
C:\Users\kosyn_000\Dropbox\OpenCVtrainingdata\negatives/IMG_20140405_214225_transparent_small.png
```

and it outputted my xml file fine; albeit taking a bit of time. Lol I can't believe it was something so simple holding me back.